# Necessity of droping column to avoid dumy variable traps in sklearn one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I tested sklearn One Hot Encoding with dropping first and without dropping first for a linear regression problem. It shows r_2 score is better when no column is dropped.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop= 'first') # r_2 score 0.67
```

with dropping first the r2_score = 0.67

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder() # r_2 score = 0.78
```

without dropping first (i,e keeping the default) r2_score = .78

So is it okay not to use drop= 'first' in Sklearn OneHotEncoding?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `drop` in `OneHotEncoder` is not meant to specify if a column should be dropped. Instead, as the official [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) states:

> Specifies a methodology to use to **drop one of the categories per feature**.

In particular, the option `drop='first'` will:

> **drop the first category in each feature**. If only one category is present, the feature will be dropped entirely.

So it can happen that a whole column is dropped, but only if it has only one category (in which case it is not useful anyway).

Regarding the change in the r2 score, the documentation addresses this issue as well:

> However, dropping one category breaks the symmetry of the original representation and can therefore induce a bias in downstream models, for instance for penalized linear classification or regression models.

Seems like this affected your model when you used `drop='first'` and it might be better to not drop any categories (and yes, you can indeed do so).

Comment: @toufique_21 did this answer your question? If yes, please accept it and consider upvoting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to read this blog piece: https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/drop-first-columns/

It contains a reasonable explanation for why your R2 is changing, plus it argues for not dropping any OHE column at all.

Answer (score 0):

And keep in mind that R2 increases when you add more features, since you need to create one new feature per each category, you are artificially increasing the R2 score

Comment: It would be great to add this as a comment, not an answer!